# Mysql Insert ColumnName is (SELECT value form another column of the same table)

Tags: mysql

Have table named `categories` like this

```
IdRows  |  CategoriesName |  UpperLevelName
--------------------------------------------
 1      |  SomeName       |
```

For example want to insert second row, that looks like this

```
IdRows  |  CategoriesName |  UpperLevelName
--------------------------------------------
 2      |  SomeNameNext   |  SomeName
```

query like this

```
INSERT INTO categories (
CategoriesName,
UpperLevelName
)
VALUES (
?,
(SELECT CategoriesName FROM categories WHERE IdRows = ?)
)
```

I mean in `UpperLevelName` want to insert `CategoriesName` where `IdRows = 1`

But get error `You can't specify target table 'categories' for update in FROM clause`

As understand error is somewhere here `(SELECT CategoriesName FROM categories WHERE IdRows = ?)`

What would be correct code?

Answer (score 0):

The `insert ... select` syntax does not contain the `values` keyword. And you need to build a temp table because in MySQL you can't update the table you are selecting from

```
INSERT INTO categories (CategoriesName, UpperLevelName)
SELECT * from 
(
   select ?, CategoriesName FROM categories WHERE IdRows = ?
) tmp
```

Comment: Thanks, understand regarding `tmp`. But with such query got `Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count`. If change to one column `INSERT INTO categories (UpperLevelName)` all works. Can not understand...

Comment: It means you want to insert 2 values but don't provide 2 in your select. You do replace the `?` in `select ?,...`with a value, right?

Comment: Yes, latter replace `?` with like `$_POST['upper_level_id']`

Comment: as understand that 'code' thinks that here `select ?, CategoriesName FROM categories WHERE IdRows = ?` is only one value...